# Desktop icons move every time after reboot

Tags: gnome, nautilus, icons, bug-reporting

Every time I run my system (Ubuntu 16.04/16.10/17.04 with GNOME installed) icons on the desktop are under top bar and when I open any window they come back to their position before turning system off.
I reinstalled system many times and on many computers and it didn't help.
I recorded and uploaded it on YouTube - link below.

[VIDEO - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g-OtIaDE8BE&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: Please give us screen shot of the issue.

Comment: Your icons are too close to the top panel. Move them lower, and they should stick.

Comment: I can't give u the screenshot because the icons are moving... All is in the video in link above. I moved icons lower and after reboot they are lower too, but after opening any program/window they move more lower like in the video :/

Comment: Same problem here, with Debian 9.5 and Gnome 3.22.2

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after reinstalling my OS (Debian 9, Gnome 3.22.2).
What solved it, was to play around with **Gnome Tweak (Tool)**. As I did not do this with "scientific rigor", I can only guess it was *switching off and on the option to have icons displayed on the desktop* or activating hibernation when the lid of my laptop is closed, which automatically *set a program to load on start up* and thus might only make it look like the problem is solved.

Comment: can you edit and add a little bit of detail , i dont apparently find a solution in what you wrote